# Valid characters in AntiForgery token __RequestVerificationToken

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I wish to know if there is a unique set of valid characters for encrypted AntiForgeryToken in ASP.NET MVC. I need to validate the key when I read it.
I have specified machineKey in my web.config.

Thanks in advance. Any suggestions regarding validation of token will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

When you peek a class `MachineKey45CryptoSystem` you will find `Protect` method that is used to serialize antiforgery token:

```
public string Protect(byte[] data)
{
    return HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(MachineKey.Protect(data, MachineKey45CryptoSystem._purposes));
}
```

When you go deeper, you will find method in `HttpEncoder`:

```
internal string UrlTokenEncode(byte[] input) {
 ....
}
```

Inside its body:

```
base64Str = Convert.ToBase64String(input);
```

and

```
// Step 3: Copy in the other chars. Transform the "+" to "-", and "/" to "_"
for (int iter = 0; iter < endPos; iter++) {
    char c = base64Str[iter];

    switch (c) {
        case '+':
            base64Chars[iter] = '-';
            break;

        case '/':
            base64Chars[iter] = '_';
            break;

        case '=':
            Debug.Assert(false);
            base64Chars[iter] = c;
            break;

        default:
            base64Chars[iter] = c;
            break;
    }
}
```

TO sum up - valid character are: letters, numbers, `-` and `_`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can we be assured that there will be no character like '!','~','*','#' in the token? Because that is not being handled in the is code.

Comment: Convert.ToBase64String ensures that. See specification of 64 base encoded string.